# Enrutar botón de retroceder de un navegador en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, botón, navegador-web

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que en mi aplicación al presionar el botón de retroceder de un navegador en vez de que me envié a la pagina anterior me envié a una ruta que yo haya establecido.

```js
//suponiendo que hay alguna forma de poner una ruta al botón de retroceder del navegador.
btnRetroceder(){
   this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}
```

Hacer algo "parecido" a eso, me da curiosidad si hay como hacer algo así. O como otra opción que no se pueda retroceder, o des habilitar el botón de retroceder del navegador. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puede que esto te sirva https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en esta pregunta, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript lo pude solucionar de esta forma:

```
 NoBackNavigator() {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event)
    {
      history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución la  he probado en Angular 8+

```
constructor (private router: Router) {
    this.volver();
 }
 volver(): void {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationStart) =>{
   if(event.navigationTrigger === "popstate"){
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).